# WCF DataMember - Weak XML Schema: Unbounded Occurences HP Fortify

Tags: xml, visual-studio, wcf, xsd, fortify

Our HP Fortify Scan is flagging us for unbounded occurrences in an XML Schema with the recommendation being to limit maxOccurs to a reasonable number.

The gist of it is: we have a WCF Service that wraps a 3rd party DLL.

In our Service, we return a "WrapperResult" object which has a list of CardData objects as one of its properties e.g.

```
[DataMember]
public List<CardData> CardData
{
    get { return cardData; }
}
```

When I add this service to my test client it generates an XSD file which looks like this:

```
<xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="CardData" nillable="true" type="tns:CardData" />
```

which is causing HP Fortify to report unbounded occurrences.

I understand I need to set maxOccurs to a reasonable number (let's say 15) - but how can I do this considering the .xsd is generated on the fly by the Add Service Reference in Visual Studio?

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: How about if you make a class which inherits from CardData, and overrides the maxOccurrs definition?

Comment: Hi @tgolisch - Considering I have the wrapper that contains a list of card data - wouldn't the constraint be there in some fashion?  e.g. can i somehow do something like [DataMember (MaxOccurs=10)].... No clue how to control the .xsd generation

Comment: You are pretty good at guessing. I think that actually is the syntax.  You can alter the .xsd files. You just have to be very careful during a refresh (ro reapply your mods).  I've also gone so far as to make a mock provider to refresh against. It is a hassle, but works-around plenty of quirks.

Comment: I do not quite think modifying the xsd directly is the correct approach here. Also [DataMember (MaxOccurs=10)] does not exist - you cannot control maxoccurs this way - I was just putting this out as something I am trying to do. I am stilld digging on this one...

Comment: was any answer found on this ?  We have the exact same issue and client won't allow application to go live as HP Fortify scan reports this as HIGH issue!!  We need to limit the maxOccurs somehow, but not sure how?

Comment: It's been so long but I think what we did was have other safeguards in place (message length) in order to circumvent this issue. So, even if it is unbounded overall message length limits will combat DOS. I am by no means an expert on the subject but I think that is the solution that was accepted.

Comment: *lightbulb* perhaps if you return an array instead of a list there would be a way to define the array upperbound and maybe that would make the XSD generate correctly? Unsure but good luck.